# How to fix a javascript function round to 1.00 instead of 0.100?

Tags: javascript

I have a function `formatMoney` that converts numbers into thousand separated strings which works close to perfect. I just noticed today that it struggles to round properly as soon as the input number is x.995xxx. It then rounds to 0.1000 instead of 1.0000.

Any way to fix this? I copied the below function from a SO thread weeks ago, but couldn't find it anymore.

```js
n1 = 0.9940
n2 = 0.9950

$('#n1').html(formatMoney(n1, 2))
$('#n2').html(formatMoney(n2, 2))

function formatMoney(n, dp){

  var s = ''+(Math.floor(n)), d = n % 1, i = s.length, r = '';
  while ( (i -= 3) > 0 ) { r = '.' + s.substr(i, 3) + r; }
  return s.substr(0, i + 3) + r +
    (d ? ',' + Math.round(d * Math.pow(10, dp || 2)) : '');
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <html>
  
    <p> Correct Output: </p>

    <div id="n1">0,9900</div>

     <p> Current wrong output: </p> 

    <div id="n2">0,1000</div>

     <p> Desired output: </p> 

    <div>1,0000</div>

  </html>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: simply `Math.round(0.99)` gives you 1

Comment: `Math.round(0.9950)` is `1`

Comment: I have updated my post to answer your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below method.

```
function formatMoney(n, digits){
        var negative = false;
        if (digits === undefined) {
            digits = 0;
        }

        if( n < 0) {
            negative = true;
          n = n * -1;
        }

        var multiplicator = Math.pow(10, digits);
        n = parseFloat((n * multiplicator).toFixed(11));
        n = (Math.round(n) / multiplicator).toFixed(digits);
        if( negative ) {    
            n = (n * -1).toFixed(2);
        }
        //return n;
        var  mystring = n.toString().replace(/\B(?<!\.\d*)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        mystring = mystring.replace(/[,.]/g, m => (m === ',' ? '.' : ','))
        return mystring;
    };
```

Comment: hmh I tried it with different numbers as input, but it never returns more than 2 digits which is what I need. Any fix to this?

Comment: @Phanti modified answer to round up based on provided digits. n = (Math.round(n) / multiplicator).toFixed(digits);

Comment: thank you, math wise it works now. Could you please show me how to fix this function even more to get ' , ' as digit separator? I could manage to change the thousand separator into ' . ' Then it will be accepted answer :) Thanks

Comment: @Phanti last two line has been modified. You can check now.

Comment: hmh it returns e.g. 3,65555 as 3,65.555 which should be just 3,65555

Comment: so e.g. 10.000.000,56789 is the desired output.

Comment: @Phanti modified answered slightly. Can you give a try now? I tried with n1 = 3.65555; which returned 3,6556 when the decimal point request is 4.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213492/discussion-between-karthick-and-phanti).

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this (updated to work with decimal point and even negative numbers)?

```js
function milesIt(num, n = 2) {
  let decimalPoint = num.toString().indexOf("."), isNegative = num < 0 && (num *= -1);
  return (isNegative && "-" || "") + Math.floor(num).toString().split("").reverse().map((n, i, a) =>
   (i + 1) % 3 === 0 && i + 1 != a.length && "." + n || n).reverse().join("") +
  (decimalPoint !== -1 && "," + num.toString().slice(decimalPoint + 1, decimalPoint + n + 1) || "");
}

let cash = -1.20389474323;
//defualt round up to 2
for(let i = 1;i < 5; i++) {
  console.log(milesIt(cash *= -10));
}
```

Comment: I need the digits separator being a comma and the thousand separator a dot

Comment: this is to far from the initial searched solution. I need the function to round to 2 digits by default and to n digits by input, like: function formatNumber (number, digit) {...}

Comment: @Phanti Ok I have updated it to round 2 as default and to work with negative numbers